# Embed 'this' within 'has' selector

Tags: jquery, this, selector

I have 2 DIV's having class 'layer' placed one over another. 
I want them to swap visibility when being clicked on a specific DIV somewhere inside of them.

```
$('.layer').not(":has(this)").show();
$('.layer:has(this)').hide();
```

It seems like JQuery interpret `'this'` not theway I expect..

What is the best way to work around?

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running this code within a context where `this` refers to a DOM element, `this` will be an object and as such cannot be appended to a string selector.

In this case you would need to use the `has()` method.

```
$('.layer').has(this).hide();
```

Alternatively, you could use optimise the logic slightly and use `closest()` instead:

```
$(this).closest('.layer').hide();
```

*Update*

Based on your comments below, you want to also select the `.layer` elements *besides* the closest parent of `this`. To do that, you can use `not()`, like this:

```
var $layer = $(this).closest('.layer').hide();
$('.layer').not($layer).show();
```

Comment: Thanx! Works fine for positive selection. But I can't reinvent this for negative selection. $(this).closest('.layer').otherInstnstanceOf('.layer').hide();

Comment: Not sure quite what you mean by negative selection. Do you mean that you want all `.layer` elements that are not the parent of `this`?